# Springdoc and prometheus

Tags: springdoc

Is it possible to gather information on prometheus end point by sprindoc?

We've recently moved from springfox library to springdoc.
Springfox was able to gather information on all end points running on the server.
Springdoc is only showing now end points configured as @RestController on code level.
There is a springdoc config property allowing to define packages to scan.
However this doesn't help, because prometheus end point is configured in springboot properties
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= prometheus

Comment: It is not possible to track Prometheus endpoints because Springdoc is a documentation library that enables support for OpenAPI in your Spring projects.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Following property is adding all `spring-boot-actuator` endpoints to swagger:

```
springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

Actuator end points themselves are configured via the property:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= prometheus
```

etc..